# reduce the size of a given image using rows and columns removing in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-resizing

I need to write a MATLAB code to reduce the size of a given image by 2 using rows and columns removing. Then explain the advantage and the disadvantage of the method i used.
How do I specify which rows and columns to delete?

Comment: Hi Farah, please add a [mre] in your question including sample input and desired output along with your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (color image):

```
im(1:end:2,:,:)=[];
im(:,1:end:2,:)=[];
```